# Keep component state using RouteReuseStrategy

Tags: angular, routes, state, router

I have a [simple app](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yfulgt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdashboard.component.ts), with two routes:

```
/dashboard => DashboardComponent
/profile   => ProfileComponent
```

The DashboardComponent has a "Load" button, which can toggle the message "*I am loading...*". Whenever I navigate out of this component, I would like to keep the state of it (still show the message "I am loading..." if the Load button has been previously pressed).

How can I achieve that? (the **ActivatedRouteSnapshot.routeConfig** is always null, so I don't know the route I am navigation to)

*Please take into consideration, that I am only interested in using the RouteReuseStrategy and not keeping the state inside a parent component.*

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary to use RouteReuseStrategy. You could keep the state in a service then use this data when user navigate back to the page. Refer to [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ceh2qe)